# IIS 7 or ASP.NET security

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm building a custom ASP.NET 4 blog app. For the admin directory I could use ASP.NET forms authentication, but since I will be the only user I'm thinking of just using IIS 7 directory security to prompt for user name and password.  Is there any reason not to do this?  Is IIS 7 security good?

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only user, it's your own machine, and you will be using NTLM then great, I'd favour it over forms any day.

I'd favour digest over forms too.

I'd favour forms over basic, but only without SSL. With SSL, I'd favour basic.

As well as preferring their security, they also don't force you to turn on sessions.